# .closest() in Capybara

Tags: jquery, capybara, closest

I'd like to find closest parent of an html element in cucumber.
just like the .closest() function of jQuery does.

this is my (pseudo) code:

```
  aspect = find('.dropdown li:contains('+selector+')')
  dropdown = aspect.closest('.dropdown') #<-- the closest() function does not exist

  if not aspect.hasClass('.selected')
    dropdown.click
    sleep 1
    aspect.click
  end
```

can anybody tell me how to accomplish this using Capybara?

Cheers!

Manuel

Answer (score 2):

This is not a universal solution, but if all you want to do is click the element, I would suggest using jQuery directly:

```
page.execute_script('$(...).closest(...).click()')
```

Other than that, Capybara does not have a .closest method, but in many cases, being more creative with selectors (possibly using XPath) might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible now using `ancestor` finder. Capybara 2.15.0 [added `ancestor` method](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/commit/548c8c00a6656520b751f0c02c0a69cfb68912bd) on 2017-08-04, so you should be able to do something like this now:

```
  aspect = find('.dropdown li:contains('+selector+')')
  dropdown = aspect.ancestor('.dropdown')
```

[Documentation for `ancestor`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#ancestor-instance_method)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
module CapybaraNodeElementExtension
  def closest(*args)
    parent = first(:xpath, './/..', wait: false)
    until parent.matches_selector?(*args)
      # return nil if not found
      if parent.matches_selector?(:xpath, '/HTML')
        parent = nil
        break
      end
      parent = parent.first(:xpath, './/..', wait: false)
    end

    parent
  end
end

Capybara::Node::Element.send(:include, CapybaraNodeElementExtension)
```

This code did not work with Version 2.18. `matches_selector?` fails. Please try 3.7.